# Unable to download file using WGET on AWS instance enabled SR

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the following topology [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A4n2.png), where there are **4 Cisco Routers** deployed in each *VPC*. I am able to ping and generate traffic from **Endpoint**1:`172.0.1.11` to **Endpoint2**:`172.2.1.10` where the traffic passes through a set of paths called **Segment Routing** which I have defined in the router `R1` *e.g.,* **(Endpoint1, R1, R2, R3, R2, R1, R2, R3, Endpoint2)**.

I have got apache installed in both instances, then I put the file that I'd like to download from the client side in the server **Endpoint1** and put into a folder `/var/www/files/`. 
Note that, both instances endpoints are in different *VPCs*.

I aim to send `100Mb` file from **Endpoint1** to **Endpoint2**.

In the client instance **Endpoint2**, I did the following:

```
curl http://172.0.1.11/files/ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso
```

I tried also:

```
wget http://172.0.1.11/files/ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso
```

the logs show:

```
172.2.1.10 - - [19/Jun/2019:13:20:24 +0000] "GET /files/ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 295317 "-" "curl/7.58.0"
```

But both are taking long time, and here what I got from **Endpoint2**

```
Connecting to 172.0.1.11:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

this is The *iptables* of **Endpoint1** is the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-0-1-11:~$ sudo iptables -L -n -v

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 517 packets, 35198 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 425 packets, 70378 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I tried with `iperf` and it sends the traffic normally.
On the server side:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-0-1-11:~$ iperf -s -u
```

and the client:

```
iperf -c 172.0.1.11 -u -b 20m 

UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 172.2.1.10 port 38402 connected with 172.0.1.11 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  23.8 MBytes  20.0 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 17008 datagrams
[  3] Server Report:
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  23.8 MBytes  20.0 Mbits/sec   0.000 ms   20/17008 (0%)
```

I even tried `telnet`. It seems that there is a connection between server and client. As well as the client side.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-2-1-10:~$ telnet 172.0.1.11 80
Trying 172.0.1.11...
Connected to 172.0.1.11.
```

Seems everything is working, except downloading the file.

Comment: It sort of sounds like an MTU issue, but it could also be the fact that you used global IP addresses that don't belong to you, instead of RFC1918 addresses.

Comment: @MichaelHampton well, I'm working within VPC private network. Those are private addresses which are given by AWS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you were right! It turns out it was *MTU* issue due the large size of the file. Is there any way to send the file like partly? I mean send part of the file until the highest value of that *MTU* then make a pause for couple of seconds till the end of file?

Answer (score -2):

**As Best i know :**

> instead of struggling with **iptables** stuff,

**Execute** below command where your HTTPD / Apache web-servers installed

```
iptables -F
```

Have a great day future **friend** .!